# how to send multidimensional array to server using retrofit android

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I am trying to send `JsonObject` to the server using Retrofit and PHP. JsonObject is generated successfully sending below JsonObject

```
{"neworder":"[{\"ItemName\":\"Sweet Pongal\",\"Cuisine\":\"Tiffen\",\"ItemId\":11,\"CuisineId\":1,\"itemType\":1,\"Quantity\":1,\"Restoid\":1,\"Mrp\":48,\"PackageCharges\":7,\"ItemCost\":48,\"distance\":1.3012003898620605,\"customerPhone\":\"9000539683\",\"customerName\":\"RAVI SHANKAR P\",\"Address\":\"45-2-40-11-5\\/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India\",\"DeliveryOptions\":\"Right now\",\"amount\":188,\"paymentMode\":\"Cash\",\"latitude\":17.7359761,\"longitude\":83.2965298},{\"ItemName\":\"Idly\",\"Cuisine\":\"Tiffen\",\"ItemId\":1,\"CuisineId\":1,\"itemType\":1,\"Quantity\":2,\"Restoid\":1,\"Mrp\":34,\"PackageCharges\":7,\"ItemCost\":68,\"distance\":1.3012003898620605,\"customerPhone\":\"9000539683\",\"customerName\":\"RAVI SHANKAR P\",\"Address\":\"45-2-40-11-5\\/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India\",\"DeliveryOptions\":\"Right now\",\"amount\":188,\"paymentMode\":\"Cash\",\"latitude\":17.7359761,\"longitude\":83.2965298}]"}
```

now I want to store this data into my server but I am not able to catch this JSON in PHP, I tried below PHP code

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

$myarray =$obj['neworder'];

if(!empty($myarray)){

$respdata['success'] = "true";
$respdata['orderid'] = $myarray;

}
```

please see below code how I am sending a Retrofit request in my android project

```
JSONArray OrderObj = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject OrderParms = null;

        for (CartUserModal cd : cartDetails) {
            int itemcost = (int) (cd.getQuantity() * cd.getMrp());

            double getdist = distance(cd.getRestlat(), cd.getRestlng(), setlatitude, setlongitue);

            try {
                OrderParms = new JSONObject();
                OrderParms.put("ItemName", cd.getItemname());
                OrderParms.put("Cuisine", cd.getCuisine());
                OrderParms.put("ItemId", cd.getItemid());
                OrderParms.put("CuisineId", cd.getCuisineid());
                OrderParms.put("itemType", cd.getItemtype());
                OrderParms.put("Quantity", cd.getQuantity());
                OrderParms.put("Restoid", cd.getRestoId());
                OrderParms.put("Mrp", cd.getMrp());
                OrderParms.put("PackageCharges", cd.getPackingcharges());
                OrderParms.put("ItemCost", itemcost);
                OrderParms.put("distance", getdist);
                OrderParms.put("customerPhone", custphone);
                OrderParms.put("customerName", custname);
                OrderParms.put("Address", delveryaddress);
                OrderParms.put("DeliveryOptions", deliveryoptions);
                OrderParms.put("amount", grandtotal);
                OrderParms.put("paymentMode", paymentoptions);
                OrderParms.put("latitude", setlatitude);
                OrderParms.put("longitude", setlongitue);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            OrderObj.put(OrderParms);
        }

        JsonObject newOrderObj = new JsonObject();
        newOrderObj.addProperty("neworder", String.valueOf(OrderObj));

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(OrderResto.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        OrderResto api = retrofit.create(OrderResto.class);

        Call<OrderResponse> call =api.SendNewPickup(newOrderObj);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OrderResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OrderResponse> call, Response<OrderResponse> response) {

                //Log.e("idoresopo", String.valueOf(response.body()));

                if(response.body().getResponse().equals("true")){

                    Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Order Placed Successfully "+response.body().getOrderid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }else if(response.body().getResponse().equals("false")){

                    Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent maininternt = new Intent(CheckoutActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(maininternt);
                    finish();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OrderResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

and my retrofit interface

```
public interface OrderResto {

    String BASE_URL = "https://api.satyamresto.com/src/routes/";

    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    @POST("orders.php")
    Call<OrderResponse> SendNewPickup(@Body JsonObject rawJsonString);
}
```

I tried the above code but not getting a response

Comment: Start with a simple `print_r($obj);` after the `json_decode()`  so you can see what is actually being passed

Comment: how can I know what data is receiving in PHP when I am sending it from retrofit to PHP?

Comment: You send it in exactly the same format every time.

Comment: yes exactly same format. do i need to change it?

Comment: I got a response I add HttpLoggingInterceptor to check the response it's working fine thank you for your help. print_r($obj); is really good idea. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is actually a JSON String inside a JSON String.

So try this in the PHP

```
$j = '{"neworder":"[{\"ItemName\":\"Sweet Pongal\",\"Cuisine\":\"Tiffen\",\"ItemId\":11,\"CuisineId\":1,\"itemType\":1,\"Quantity\":1,\"Restoid\":1,\"Mrp\":48,\"PackageCharges\":7,\"ItemCost\":48,\"distance\":1.3012003898620605,\"customerPhone\":\"9000539683\",\"customerName\":\"RAVI SHANKAR P\",\"Address\":\"45-2-40-11-5\\/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India\",\"DeliveryOptions\":\"Right now\",\"amount\":188,\"paymentMode\":\"Cash\",\"latitude\":17.7359761,\"longitude\":83.2965298},{\"ItemName\":\"Idly\",\"Cuisine\":\"Tiffen\",\"ItemId\":1,\"CuisineId\":1,\"itemType\":1,\"Quantity\":2,\"Restoid\":1,\"Mrp\":34,\"PackageCharges\":7,\"ItemCost\":68,\"distance\":1.3012003898620605,\"customerPhone\":\"9000539683\",\"customerName\":\"RAVI SHANKAR P\",\"Address\":\"45-2-40-11-5\\/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India\",\"DeliveryOptions\":\"Right now\",\"amount\":188,\"paymentMode\":\"Cash\",\"latitude\":17.7359761,\"longitude\":83.2965298}]"}';

$obj = json_decode($j,1);
print_r($obj);

$neworder = json_decode($obj['neworder'],1);
print_r($neworder);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [neworder] => [{"ItemName":"Sweet Pongal","Cuisine":"Tiffen","ItemId":11,"CuisineId":1,"itemType":1,"Quantity":1,"Restoid":1,"Mrp":48,"PackageCharges":7,"ItemCost":48,"distance":1.3012003898620605,"customerPhone":"9000539683","customerName":"RAVI SHANKAR P","Address":"45-2-40-11-5/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India","DeliveryOptions":"Right now","amount":188,"paymentMode":"Cash","latitude":17.7359761,"longitude":83.2965298},{"ItemName":"Idly","Cuisine":"Tiffen","ItemId":1,"CuisineId":1,"itemType":1,"Quantity":2,"Restoid":1,"Mrp":34,"PackageCharges":7,"ItemCost":68,"distance":1.3012003898620605,"customerPhone":"9000539683","customerName":"RAVI SHANKAR P","Address":"45-2-40-11-5/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India","DeliveryOptions":"Right now","amount":188,"paymentMode":"Cash","latitude":17.7359761,"longitude":83.2965298}]
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ItemName] => Sweet Pongal
            [Cuisine] => Tiffen
            [ItemId] => 11
            [CuisineId] => 1
            [itemType] => 1
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Restoid] => 1
            [Mrp] => 48
            [PackageCharges] => 7
            [ItemCost] => 48
            [distance] => 1.3012003898621
            [customerPhone] => 9000539683
            [customerName] => RAVI SHANKAR P
            [Address] => 45-2-40-11-5/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India
            [DeliveryOptions] => Right now
            [amount] => 188
            [paymentMode] => Cash
            [latitude] => 17.7359761
            [longitude] => 83.2965298
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ItemName] => Idly
            [Cuisine] => Tiffen
            [ItemId] => 1
            [CuisineId] => 1
            [itemType] => 1
            [Quantity] => 2
            [Restoid] => 1
            [Mrp] => 34
            [PackageCharges] => 7
            [ItemCost] => 68
            [distance] => 1.3012003898621
            [customerPhone] => 9000539683
            [customerName] => RAVI SHANKAR P
            [Address] => 45-2-40-11-5/1, Ramachandra Nagar, Akkayyapalem, Visakhapatnam, Andhra Pradesh 530016, India
            [DeliveryOptions] => Right now
            [amount] => 188
            [paymentMode] => Cash
            [latitude] => 17.7359761
            [longitude] => 83.2965298
        )

)
```

Comment: I am doing this in a server, can print raw JSON but while I send it from retrofit i am not able to catch it in PHP. please see my php code. i dont know what request i am getting in php